# EWS - Retrieve Required Attendees from GetUserAvailability

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm trying to retrieve the `RequiredAttendees` property of an `Appointment`, but the `Appointment.ID` returned from the `GetUserAvailabilityRequest` appears to be malformed.

I say it appears to be malformed because I have attempted to do an `Appointment.Bind` on that `ID` and I receive that error. I also tried doing a `ConvertIdRequest`, but that also informed me that the `ID` was malformed. Has anyone been successful in retrieving additional properties from an `Appointment` in the `GetUserAvailabilityRequest` function?

```
<m:GetUserAvailabilityRequest>
    <m:MailboxDataArray>
        <t:MailboxData>
            <t:Email>
                <t:Address>room_email@email.com</t:Address>
            </t:Email>
            <t:AttendeeType>Required</t:AttendeeType>
            <t:ExcludeConflicts>false</t:ExcludeConflicts>
        </t:MailboxData>
    </m:MailboxDataArray>
    <t:FreeBusyViewOptions>
        <t:TimeWindow>
            <t:StartTime>2016-11-23T00:00:00</t:StartTime>
            <t:EndTime>2016-11-23T23:59:59</t:EndTime>
        </t:TimeWindow>
        <t:MergedFreeBusyIntervalInMinutes>30</t:MergedFreeBusyIntervalInMinutes>
        <t:RequestedView>Detailed</t:RequestedView>
    </t:FreeBusyViewOptions>
</m:GetUserAvailabilityRequest>
```

Updated:

Added in `ConvertId` request:

```
<ConvertId xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages' xmlns:t='http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' 
    DestinationFormat='EwsId'>
    <SourceIds>
        <t:AlternateId Format='EntryId' Id='00000000816E21AD59E7904981DE99604E0CC83507002DB2B0714B541545B1DA6BDA0C682DFA00000000010D00002DB2B0714B541545B1DA6BDA0C682DFA000039D00A690000' Mailbox='room_email@email.com' />
    </SourceIds>
</ConvertId>
```

Comment: GetUserAvailabilityRequest returns the hexId of the appointment so you would have to use ConvertId with the correct formats to convert that to an EWSId. I would guess that the problem is more to do with your ConvertId request can you post that with one of the HexId's your trying to convert ?

Comment: Thanks @GlenScales. I've added the ConvertId request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ConvertId request isn't correct your using EntryId which means you should have then base64 encoded the EntryId. What you can do is use HexEntryId format instead which would make your request valid eg the following works okay for me (ConvertId is algorithmic meaning any Exchange server can convert it)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
      <m:ConvertId DestinationFormat="EwsId">
        <m:SourceIds>
          <t:AlternateId Format="HexEntryId" Id="00000000816E21AD59E7904981DE99604E0CC83507002DB2B0714B541545B1DA6BDA0C682DFA00000000010D00002DB2B0714B541545B1DA6BDA0C682DFA000039D00A690000" Mailbox="gscales@mailbox.com" />
        </m:SourceIds>
      </m:ConvertId>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Had a feeling it was as simple as understanding the Id format...much appreciated.